# MySQL queries hardcoded or dynamically built in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

Most PHP tutorials oriented on connection with MySQL database has hardcoded queries cooperating with prepare-type functions. I haven't seen any tutorials on dynamically built queries.

What if I had an idea to split a table into 2 separete ones joined by foreign key. I would have to update every single query I wrote in PHP which uses this table. It would be nicer if there would be something like a query-builder object which would create a subquery returning our desired table. Any query operating on this table would have to operate on a subquery and the point is - if we change the table structure the only thing we have to change in the PHP code is the part creating the subquery.

The very important part is that we don't do mulitple queries at any point in this idea. We are just building one big query which is slightly more object oriented.

I don't see anyone using anything like dynamically created queries so there has to be a mistake in my reasoning and the question is: where?

Comment: The tutorials you're seeing are probably, statistically speaking, pretty superficial. An ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/),
[Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or 
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) makes it easy to dynamically compose queries using query builders and techniques like scoping. It's always better to avoid hard-coded queries if you can, or low-level SQL in general, though there are situations where it's unavoidable or preferential from an absolute performance perspective.

Comment: Thank you very much! ORM is probably the thing I was looking for but I couldn't name it.

Comment: A good ORM won't cramp your style, it'll help you get more work done, faster. If you do find you're fighting the ORM more often than it's helping, try a different one.